# Latest record up to a certain date

Tags: django

Given following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Containing following records:

```
1/May/2016: a
20/May/2016: b
3/Nov/2016: c
15/Nov/2016: d
```

I would like to get the latest record up to a certain date, e.g. `latest_up_to_date(18/August/2016)` should return `b`.

Comment: How does a model contain two fields with same name?

Comment: @arulmr: because that's a copy/paste error. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date_val = datetime.datetime.strptime('1/Aug/2016', '%d/%b/%Y')    
MyModel.objects.filter(date__lte=date_val).latest('date')
```

Comment: That's another way to do it. Accepting this one instead of my own reply.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the newer objects first, and then use `latest()`:

```
latest_up_to_date = None
try:
    latest_up_to_date = MyModel.objects.exclude(date__gt=datetime.date(2016, 8, 18)).latest('date')
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
    pass
```